# Configuring "hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled" throws an exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using `Hibernate 6.1.4` and `Jakarta Persistence 3.1` with `JDK 11.0.16.1+1.`

Support for `<hibernate-mappings>` is deprecated, so when I configure `"hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled"` in `hibernate.cfg` it throws an exception.

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.boot.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document: com/retailfx/pojo/Items.hbm.xml (RESOURCE)  

Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document: com/retailfx/pojo/Items.hbm.xml (RESOURCE)  

Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: OneToMany transformation not yet implemented : origin(com/retailfx/pojo/Items.hbm.xml)
```

**hibernate.cfg**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/retailfx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">derby</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_catalog"/>
           
        <property name="hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled">true</property>
        
        <mapping resource="com/retailfx/pojo/Items.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Items.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.retailfx.pojo.Items" table="ITEMS" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="itemname" type="string">
            <column name="ITEMNAME" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="cost" type="string">
            <column name="COST" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="quantity" type="string">
            <column name="QUANTITY" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="saleses" table="SALES" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="ITID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.retailfx.pojo.Sales" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Sales.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.retailfx.pojo.Sales" table="SALES" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
       
        <many-to-one name="items" class="com.retailfx.pojo.Items" fetch="select">
            <column name="ITID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="itemname" type="string">
            <column name="ITEMNAME" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="cost" type="string">
            <column name="COST" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="quantity" type="string">
            <column name="QUANTITY" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="total" type="string">
            <column name="TOTAL" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am not using `@annotations`

What is the exact cause of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that transformation of one-to-many associations is not yet implemented, so the following mapping has to be transformed manually right now:

```xml
        <set name="saleses" table="SALES" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="ITID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.retailfx.pojo.Sales" />
        </set>
```

You can also create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

You can also follow the existing enhancement request https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15334 and comment on it about your use case.

Comment: How to transform manual mapping? Do you mean discard hxm.xml and use @annotations?

Comment: Switch to JPA orm.xml or the Hibernate extension of that, or use annotations.